# How to store "wishlist" in database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am thinking of creating a "wishlist". Each user will be able to purchase wishes in a shop. How do I store the wishlist? I am thinking of creating an user table and a wishlist table.

The structure of user table:
Columns: id, username, password etc

Columns: id, wish, price, quantity etc

user id is the primary key for user table and its a foreign key in wishlist table. However, when I come to think of it, my wishlist table will have duplicate items for each user, won't it?

Is there a better way to store the wishlist things?

I am  using mysql. Thanks

Comment: In many ways this question has no concrete answer.  Ask 100 analysts for a design and get 100 different answers, all more or less correct. As the architect of this system you ultimately have to decide for yourself.

Comment: I want the most secure and popular method. I am new to database, so I seek for guidances..

Comment: security is only loosely related to the design of your tables.

Comment: edg: I would disagree there. For a relatively simple database design, you are most likely going to see a lot more agreement from experienced database designers because they will generally follow the same basic rules and principles of normalization and table relationships. Of course there may be minor discrepancies, but the general layout would most likely be similar for something like this which would require very few tables.

Comment: @TheTXI: You may be right, on the other hand there are currently three answers all different.  "Good" designs might emerge as patterns but the "best" will always be context sensitive and best decided by the architect closest to the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You should also have another table to store the purchases:

Purchases

- Id
- UserId
- WishId
- PurchaseDate

Users

- Id
- Name
- Password

Wishes

- Id
- Wish
- Price
- Quantity

Every time a user purchases a wish, you create a record in the Purchases table, and decrement the Quantity count for that wish.

Comment: can u be more specific? Thats mean i need to create 3 tables? Can u list the sample important column names for each?

Comment: This is the most logical way of structuring based upon the question asker's specifications. You may wish to edit further to make note that if you are decrementing the quantity on every purchase, you would want to increment the quantity whenever you receive new stock.

Answer (score 0):

It is a 1 to n relationship.

Asuming you have a User table with a user_id as primary key then
create a table Wish which has user_id as foreign key.
Add the attributes you want to this second table and violá.

Luis

Answer (score 0):

You should have another table for wishes (wish id, price, description etc), and you should have a joining table (user id, wish id, quantity, quoted price etc).  This table will allow you to have a many-to-many relationship between users and wishes.

(Further to my comment... see?  You have **two** different suggestions already.  Ultimately you have to decide what is best, and ideally your business/project requirements should guide you.)

**EDIT**: make that **three** different suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need to know just a few things to add information to a wishlist. Here's how I have it in one of my client projects:

**Wishlist**

- wishlist_id
- user_id
- product_id
- created_date_time

It would make sense to have wishlists only for authenticated users, so ensure that you are taking care of that.